# type '(PlatformException) => void' is not a subtype of type '(Object) => FutureOr<dynamic> Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using Event Channels in Flutter to return beacon data from Native SDK to Flutter. This was working fine until a recent Flutter upgrade.Now, I am getting the following error.

`type '(PlatformException) => void' is not a subtype of type '(Object) => FutureOr<dynamic>`

with the following stack trace:

```
#0      _registerErrorHandler (dart:async/async_error.dart:22:60)
#1      _BufferingStreamSubscription.onError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:146:16)
#2      new _BufferingStreamSubscription (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:113:10)
#3      new _ControllerSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart)
#4      new _BroadcastSubscription (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart)
#5      _BroadcastStreamController._subscribe (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:212:46)
#6      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:817:19)
#7      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:466:9)
#8      _MyHomePageState.initPlatformState.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/chaythanyanair/Documents/Qburst/Learn/flutter_poc/lib/main.dart:95:43)
#9      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1381:54)
#10     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
#11     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:633:45)
#12     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:662:32)
#13     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:467:7)
#14     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#15     MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     _MyHomePageState.initPlatformState.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/chaythanyanair/Documents/Qburst/Learn/flutter_poc/lib/main.dart:89:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#17     _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1381:54)
#18     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
#19     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:633:45)
#20     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:662:32)
#21     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:467:7)
#22     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#23     User_Profile.getUser (package:flutter_poc/Models/User.dart)
<asynchronous suspension>
#24     _MyHomePageState.initPlatformState (file:///Users/chaythanyanair/Documents/Qburst/Learn/flutter_poc/lib/main.dart:69:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#25     _MyHomePageState.initState (file:///Users/chaythanyanair/Documents/Qburst/Learn/flutter_poc/lib/main.dart:52:5)
#26     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3734:58)
#27     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3600:5)
#28     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
#29     Element.updateChild
```

This is my EventChannel implementation:

```
static const platform = const MethodChannel('samples.flutter.io/initialiseRanging');
static const stream =
  const EventChannel('samples.flutter.io/ranging');
try {
        await platform.invokeMethod('initialiseRanging').then((result){
          print(result);
          setState(() {
            _currentValue = result;
          });

          stream.receiveBroadcastStream().listen(_onEvent, onError: _onError);
        });

  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
        print( "{e.message}");
  }
```

This is how the `_onEvent` and `_onError` functions are implemented.

```
void _onEvent(Object event) {
    setState(() {
      _currentValue = event.toString();
    });
    print(event);
}

void _onError(PlatformException error) {
    print(error);
}
```

Any idea on why this could possible happen?

Comment: What Flutter version are you using? Try switching to `dev` channel

Comment: I am already on `dev` channel. Still the getting the issue.

Comment: What does `_onError()` look like?

Comment: and what does it look like?

Comment: I have updated the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void _onError(PlatformException error) {
```

should be

```
void _onError(Object error) {
```

Even when you are only interested in `PlatformException` or even when this is the only exception that happened so far, doesn't mean there can't be others. The expected handler function needs to match the parameter type, instead of only the exceptions you expect.

Comment: Glat to hear . .

Comment: Also ran into the same issue if you don't pass in any arguments to _onError. This helped tremendously!